# where to download the EntityFramework.sqlserver source code?

Tags: entity-framework

I have download the entityframework srouce code , but I can not find the source code relative to entityframework.sqlserver.dll .
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download it from CodePlex here: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest. `EntityFramework.SqlServer` is one the of the projects in the solution that gets downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is for EF 6.x branch. The current dev branch and future releases (including EntityframeworkCore.SQLServer), is now hosted on Git Hub - https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework